# dvisvgm won't create text, only paths, no matter what option

Tags: pdf, svg, dvisvgm

Hope you're all doing well.

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place for this, but I'm creating a piece of software and it requires an SVG to work, but the user must input a PDF. I am trying to use `dvisvgm` to convert the PDF to an SVG, but it is converting all the text into `paths`, rather than `text` elements.

I've tried many solutions, but I can't find a way from the manual to convert the text in the PDF to text SVG elements.

`dvisvgm.exe --font-format=ttf --pdf example.pdf` seems to produce the exact same thing as `dvisvgm.exe --pdf example.pdf`, doing `dvisvgm.exe --pdf example.pdf`. `font-format` doesn't affect anything, neither does `--optimize`, it's really odd.

It seems like every command seems to be running as if it has the argument `‑‑no‑fonts`, despite not being the case.

Please help me if you can. Sorry if I'm missing anything really obvious, this is my first time using this kind of tool.

If it's important, I'm using the version of dvisvgm which comes as a package with MikTeX.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is documented behavior. According to the man page of `dvisvgm`:

> Text present in PDF and PostScript files is always converted to path elements.

So `dvisvgm`'s support to really embed fonts does only work when converting DVI files, not when converting PDF or EPS files.

Comment: God that's annoying, thank you. Looks like I'll be using Inkscape + SVGo instead. Thanks again